# Increase wireless handoff frequency

Tags: wifi

I understand which Apple devices support wireless AP handoffs, though when roaming around our office with my Macbook Pro it usually takes my mac about 5 minutes to actually assess which access point may be more optimal and to trigger a handoff.

Is there a way to increase the frequency of handoff scans, or simply decrease the time it takes for the system to detect there is a better access point?

As I mentioned it's a MacBook Pro with Yosemite preinstalled. It's the second newest version (as in the version that is one iteration behind the newly announced MacBook Pros).

Comment: If it takes 5 min to switch they are not same SSID/AP/Chanel ect types.

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's the same AP going from b/g/n to ac

Comment: The actual switching should not be more than 30 seconds, so something else is in play here. What is your OS X ? do you have single SSID profile or multiple?

Comment: 10.10, and just a single.

Comment: did you try this http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply, since the laptop came preinstalled with Yosemite

Comment: You're right. Please include this usefull info. (+ Yosemite version) within your original question. The 1st one wasn't dry on market exit. Comments aren't aimed to stay.

Comment: No way to control this from the client side on OS X, however some APs allow configuring thresholds for handoff (Unify enabled APs).

Comment: @mspasov Is there a term I could be searching for to look for that? We're running Unify APs conveniently. If you fashion it into an on-topic answer I'll accept it too :)

Comment: @Qix It's called 'minrssi', and it's manually configured in a text file. Visit the community site, there should be more information.